# Unpivot PySpark dataframe after grouping by the same column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Looking for any leads for transforming dataframe X to Y.

I've tried using unpivot after grouping by **A**i's and country columns. Apparently, it's not possible to unpivot on a column after grouping by the same column.
Some completely different approaches will also do.

**X:**

```
A1,A2,A3,country
True,False,True,"USA"
False,False,False,"USA"
False,True,False,"USA"
False,False,True,"USA"
False,False,False,"USA"
True,False,False,"RUS"
False,True,False,"RUS"
False,False,False,"RUS"
False,False,False,"RUS"
True,False,False,"ENG"
False,False,True,"ENG"
False,False,False,"CHN"
```

**Y:**

```
A1,A2,A3,country
1,1,2,"USA"
1,1,0,"RUS"
1,0,1,"ENG"
0,0,0,"CHN"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by country and sum up the other columns:

```
df2 = df.groupBy('country').agg(*[F.sum(F.col(c).cast('int')).alias(c) for c in ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']])

df2.show()
+-------+---+---+---+
|country| A1| A2| A3|
+-------+---+---+---+
|    ENG|  1|  0|  1|
|    USA|  1|  1|  2|
|    RUS|  1|  1|  0|
|    CHN|  0|  0|  0|
+-------+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @mck's answer, but you for Spark 3+ you can use [`count_if`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#count_if) function instead of casting to int and summing :

```
df1 = df.groupby("country").agg(
    *[F.expr(f"count_if({c})").alias(c) for c in df.columns if c != "country"]
)

df1.show()

#+-------+---+---+---+
#|country| A1| A2| A3|
#+-------+---+---+---+
#|    ENG|  1|  0|  1|
#|    USA|  1|  1|  2|
#|    RUS|  1|  1|  0|
#|    CHN|  0|  0|  0|
#+-------+---+---+---+
```